# UPDATE stored procedure with conditional arguments

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I want to write an Oracle UPDATE stored procedure where I reset certain fields if BIT argument is true. If BIT argument is not true, then update should take the already existing value or skip updating the field. How can I achieve this?

What I am trying to achieve more or less is this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE [dbo].[p_update_fields]
    @ID                  varchar(255),
    @RESET_FIELD_1    boolean,
    @RESET_FIELD_2    boolean,
    @RESET_FIELD_3    boolean
    
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
        IF EXISTS (SELECT id FROM dbo.TABLE_NAME WHERE id = @ID)
            declare field1_;
            declare field2_;
            select t.field1, t.field2 INTO field1_, field2_ FROM dbo.TABLE_NAME t where t.id = @ID
            if(@RESET_FIELD_1 = true) 
               field1_ = null;
            if(@RESET_FIELD_2 = true)
               field2_ = null;
            UPDATE dbo.TABLE_NAME
                SET
                    field1 = field1_,
                    field2 = field2_
            WHERE id = @ID
    END TRANSACTION
    SET NOCOUNT OFF;
END
```

Comment: As code you posted isn't Oracle & I don't quite understand what you wrote ("reset certain fields"? Reset *how*?) ("BIT argument is not true"? there's no BIT datatype in Oracle, so ... what does that mean?), it would help if you posted some sample data and desired result, along with values you'd pass to the procedure. Or - wait for someone who understands this code and also knows Oracle. I know there are such people here; just be patient.

Comment: Sorry, I am quite new at stored procedures. I've updated the question, does that help. Basically if I have a table, and I would like to reset (set null) specific columns on that table based on the arguments given to the stored procedure, what I just wrote would be ok?

Comment: No, your code will not compile on Oracle as it is using SQL Server syntax and not Oracle syntax. You: cannot use `@` or `[]` with identifiers; nor use `SET NOCOUNT ON;` or `BEGIN TRANSACTION`; have `DECLARE` without the rest of the PL/SQL `BEGIN ... END;` block; cannot use `IF EXISTS(...)`; and `BOOLEAN` is a PL/SQL only data-type which cannot be used in SQL statements. There is an error on most of the lines of your procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do use Oracle, then have a look at the following example. I chose not to pass Boolean but numeric values (they are simpler to use; 1 represents "true", 0 is then "false").

Sample data:

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY id;

ID       FIELD1     FIELD2     FIELD3
---- ---------- ---------- ----------
A123        100        200        300
B456          1          2          3
```

Procedure:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p_update_fields (par_id       IN VARCHAR2,
  2                                               par_reset_1  IN NUMBER,
  3                                               par_reset_2  IN NUMBER,
  4                                               par_reset_3  IN NUMBER)
  5  IS
  6  BEGIN
  7     UPDATE table_name
  8        SET field1 = CASE WHEN par_reset_1 = 1 THEN NULL ELSE field1 END,
  9            field2 = CASE WHEN par_reset_2 = 1 THEN NULL ELSE field2 END,
 10            field3 = CASE WHEN par_reset_3 = 1 THEN NULL ELSE field3 END
 11      WHERE id = par_id;
 12  END;
 13  /

Procedure created.
```

Testing: let's reset just `FIELD1` for `ID = 'A123'`:

```
SQL> BEGIN
  2     p_update_fields (par_id       => 'A123',
  3                      par_reset_1  => 1,
  4                      par_reset_2  => 0,
  5                      par_reset_3  => 0);
  6  END;
  7  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Result:

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY id;

ID       FIELD1     FIELD2     FIELD3
---- ---------- ---------- ----------
A123                   200        300     --> FIELD1 is now NULL
B456          1          2          3

SQL>
```